# Media center consumes all available memory when attempting to play music off of a server

Tags: windows-7, music, windows-media-center, streaming, windows-home-server

I have Windows 7 Ultimate, and recently, when i try to play a song off of my Twonky Media Server/Windows Media Connect (based on an HP WHS with an Atom), it plays choppily. When i open Resource Monitor, it shows that after ordering the music to play, memory usage rapidly spikes to consume most, if not all, of the available memory on my system (excluding a couple hundred megabytes in standby). Why does it do this and is there anything i can do to stop it?

Edit: it happens when I attempt to browse the server's music, not just when i play music.

Edit 2: the "ehshell" process is what consumes the memory, appears to me something specific to media center. Moreover, the ehshell process doesn't die in this case.

Edit 3: It only happens when browsing my Twonky library, and not my Windows Media Connect.

Comment: Does this happen if you use Media Player?

Comment: Nope. (15 chars)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, ehshell is the core component of Media Center. Where the bug lies, I really couldn't tell you. However, unless there's something you need from the Twonky version, why not just use the WMC version?

Comment: This is a good point, but i want to know WHY it does this

Comment: It appears that ehshell is used by MCE to record/encode/transcode.

Comment: Ehshell is actually the center of the action in MCE. It presents the interface, manages the recording processes, etc.